# Create child object in parent constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

Is it possible to create an instance of a child object using the parent's constructor and passing it some kind of parameter (a string, in this case) to tell it the type of child that should be created?

Comment: Is the child object's type inherited from the parent's type? If so, you are looking for a factory method.

Comment: +1 Oliver : sounds definitely like a factory to me too.

Comment: I'd recommend reading : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. In C#, you create an instance of a class, *then* the runtime calls its constructor. By the time the constructor executes it's too late to pick another type.

However, a derived class' constructor always calls one of its base class' constructors, and you can use that to your advantage (to avoid repeating code).

People often create [factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) to do what you're talking about. For example, given the classes `Parent`, `Child1:Parent`, and `Child2:Parent`, you might write a factory like this:

```
public class ParentFactory {
    public Parent CreateParent(string type) {
        switch(type) {
            case "Child1":
                return new Child1();
            case "Child2":
                return new Child2();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected type");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a class **A** and a class **B that derives from A**. Then you want to call `new A("B")` and this should return you a new B object?

**That is not possible.**

However, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe you should check out **reflection**, because it allows you to create an instance of a class by its name string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dex1ss7c.aspx

```
var obj = myAssembly.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClassB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood right, but here is what I understood :)

```
public class parent:child
{
    private child childObj;
    public parent(string childName)
    {
        childObj = new child(childName);
    }

}
public class child
{
    private string name;

    public child(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite that. It does the same as the answer provided by GenericTypeTea, which is not what I wanted.